# How to use windows bootloader to dual boot windows and ubuntu on uefi?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, uefi, bootloader, bcdedit

What I exactly tried is...

Installed windows 10 with uefi.

Installed Ubuntu 17.04 with uefi on the 20GB drive. The ubuntu bootloader is installed on the efi system partition created while installing windows 10, by selecting the "Windows Boot Manager" when asked for partitioning during wizard for installing Ubuntu. 
So, after the installation of ubuntu, my EFI Firmware Menu (UEFI Boot Menu) shows like:
[SSD with windows(Legacy)]
[DVD-ROM]
[USB Drive]
[UEFI: USB Drive]
ubuntu

The default selection was the "ubuntu" and that lead to the grub loader.

What exactly I wanted was when I start my computer, windows boot loader must provide option like the blue screen as shown below, to select between the windows and ubuntu.
[Bootloader Image That I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A12nL.png)

So I tried booting from my windows 10 efi usb installed, select repair my computer and opened command prompt. And used bcdedit to edit the bootloader.

I make changes like...

deleted the "ubuntu" firmware application to remove the grub loader.

Add a "Windows Boot Loader" but command

`"bcdedit /create /d "Ubuntu" /application /osloader"`
and set path to "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi"

so my bcd configuration seems like k
Windows Boot Manager that links bootmgfw.efi.
Windows Boot Loader (Windows 10)that links winload.efi
Windows Boot Loader (Ubuntu) that links shimx64.efi //(That I added)

So I got the black and white Windows Boot Manager instead the Graphical Blue Boot loader and also its unable to boot to ubuntu by throwing an error.

---

What exactly I want is a blue screen with two options from windows blue boot loader and since I have uefi based installation, I can't use EasyBCD.
Please help.

Answer (score -3):

Try EasyUEFI instead of EasyBCD

Comment: Could you please explain why?  That would make a much better answer.